# How do I dynamically add tables in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

After hours searching through almost every code related website and still not having found a solution I finally ask my question here and hope for an answer (or many).

I am creating an android app that gets messages sent from a server. Different clients can emit those messages and my app should be able to

1. (first create) check if there is already a user specific table in db
2. if not create one (or more over time) dynamically

So my question more precicely is how I can create new tables over time whenever a so far unknown user sends data.
I do not want the tables to be predefined in my dbhelper class but rather have them dynamically built.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can not just use one table to store the data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890241/error-when-trying-to-insert-values-in-dynamically-created-table-in-android-sqlit                                       I posted the same issue but with code on a different thread

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I think queries for data from just one user will take too long over time when there is lots of data later on so this is why I want to create a different table for every different user

Comment: So you should add an index on userId

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to create tables dynamically. In the case you are describing (if I understand it properly) you can have two tables. A messages table, and a users table. Therefore your schema would look something like this.

```
Users
id | user
---------
1  | joe
2  | jane
3  | jack

Messages
id  | user | message
--------------------
1   |  2   | "hi joe!"
2   |  1   | "How are you Jane?"
3   |  1   | "And jack, what about you?"
4   |  3   | "Hi guys. What's up?"
```

Now, your messages may not be chat messages like this one, but the idea still stands. Have two separate tables. One for users, and one for messages, that way you can keep all your messages together in one table, and identify the associated user by their user id.

Ideally the users column on the Messages table should have a foreign key constraint too.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to create tables dynamically but I'm concerned that over time the amount of users and messages get too much for just one table (in a sense that queries for one specific user will take too long)

Comment: the messages could exactly look like the ones u sent

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a singleton class that deals with your database and has methods that you will be using from other classes. I would create something of this sort:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
  private static DBHandler dbh = null;
  private static SQLiteDatabase DB = null;

  private DBHandler(Context context)
  {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    ctx = context;
  }

  public static synchronized DBHandler getInstance(Context c)
  {
    if (dbh == null)
      dbh = new DBHandler(c);
    return dbh;
  }

  private SQLiteDatabase getDB()
  {
    if (DB != null)
      return DB;
    return this.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void createTab(String tabname)
  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getDB();

    try
    {
      String stmt = "CREATE TABLE " + tabname + ... // the rest of your statement
      db.execSQL(stmt);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But what you need to consider is the fact that tables are usually not created dynamically. If you need to do it frequently enough, then your schema is lacking some design and will very quickly pollute your catalogs. Can you please post exactly what you are storing? That way I can offer a better schema design which can render all these tables creations unnecessary.

Comment: could u pls elaborate how those other classes could look like, what they provide?

Comment: Hi Dave, not sure what you mean by other classes. There is only one class in use here: SQLiteDatabase, which is part of android. The other one (DBHandler) is the one you're creating.

Comment: btw, I see you reply to user5942149 - you shouldn't be concerned with the size of the table - database can handle large tables without problems (few billion records). You do need to create a primary key, so the table is indexed. Whenever you write your queries (i.e. SELECT ... ) always! use filters with keys for speedy access (i.e. ... WHERE id = 27 AND message_id = 253). This way you don't need to worry about the size of the table and everything will continue working fast. However, if you write something like SELECT * FROM ... that would definitely be slower and slower as your table grows.