# Error when trying to insert values in dynamically created table in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have following function in my service:

```
private void saveToDB(String sender, String message, String time) {
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext(), sender);
    db.insertOrCreateTable(sender, message, time);
}
```

This is my db handler class:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Mo";
    private static String mSender;

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_SENDER ="sender";
    private static final String KEY_MSG = "msg";
    private static final String KEY_TIME ="time";

    //constructor
    public DBHandler(Context context, String sender) {
        //higher db version when user needs to create new table
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        mSender = sender;
    }

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_MESSAGES = mSender;

    private String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "Create Table " + TABLE_MESSAGES + 
              "("   
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_SENDER + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_MSG + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";



    // Creating Tables
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if exists
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MESSAGES);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void insertOrCreateTable(String s,String m,String t) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_SENDER, s); // Message Sender
        values.put(KEY_MSG, m); // Message Message
        values.put(KEY_TIME, t); // Message Time

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(mSender, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Now, I try to create tables dynamically but it always returns an error:

```
    E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "65": syntax error
    03-09 12:03:13.813 20828-21609/com.example.asus.service E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting sender=65 time=12:03 msg=C
                                                                              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "65": syntax error (

code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 65(sender,time,msg) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Any Ideas or suggestions? Also I posted this in a thread in a different way so feel free to look at it too (might help u understand my problem better)
Here's the link: [How do I dynamically add tables in android sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873442/how-do-i-dynamically-add-tables-in-android-sqlite/35873977#35873977)

What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: what's the value of `mSender `?

Comment: You are passing 65 as sender value. Make it as a string value.

Comment: your `insert();` is doing an implict ROLLBACK. you need to be in a transaction (and COMMIT it) for the data to be saved.

Comment: @FebiMathew but 65 is a string value?!

Comment: @DavidM how do I perform that? never heard of that before could u explain?

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 db.beginTransaction()

...insert, update, delete, etc

if (ok) {
db.setTransactionSucessful();
}
db.endTransaction();
db.close();

https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html. Sqlite is similar to SQL Server in this regard. if you don't wrap CRUD operations in Transaction, you are implicitly rolling back your changes. try it!

Answer (score 0):

If your table has name `65` you should use `' '` to insert.
Instead of:

`INSERT INTO 65(sender,time,msg) VALUES (?,?,?)`

try:

`INSERT INTO '65'(sender,time,msg) VALUES (?,?,?)`

Comment: thanks for ur post. but I don't quite get it cuz 65 is a string... also where should use ' '?

Comment: Just try and you'll see :) I think you should.